# Disposing a IConnectableObservable doesn't send OnComplete

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've stumbled across a problem while trying to deal with a worst case; that being disposing of a `IConnectableObservable`, that has subscriptions, before it has finished.

I've written a contrived example that reproduces the problem.

```
var hotSource = Observable
    .Return(1)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
    .Publish();

var disposable = hotSource.Connect();
```

Here is my hot observable. I've added a delay in so that I can subscribe to it before it fires off the value.

Below I return an awaitable observable that should allow me to wait until the hotSource is complete. I believe I should be subscribed by this point

```
var awaitable = hotSource
    .Do((Console.WriteLine))
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Complete"))
    .LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

Now if I dispose immediately then await my subscription:

```
disposable.Dispose();
await awaitable;
```

it simply hangs the application entirely and `Finally` is never called.

I'm expecting my `awaitable` to return either `OnCompleted` or at worst `OnError` with `ObjectDisposedException`. Also, if you connect after the subscription, it still hangs. Any thoughts?

**[Update]**

Taking supertoi's answer (that I wasn't subscribing until after the dispose) I've reformulated the problem with an explicit subscription before the dispose.

```
var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

var hotSource = Observable
    .Return(1)
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
    .Publish();

var subscription = Observable.Create(
    (IObserver<int> observer) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribed");
        return hotSource.Subscribe(observer);
    })
    .Finally(() => mutex.Release())
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

hotSource
    .Connect()
    .Dispose();

await mutex.WaitAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Complete");
```

This again halts, but its defiantly subscribing to the `IConnectableObservable` before it has been disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastOrDefaultAsync()` returns an `IObservable` so it does not subscribe you to the sequence. 
The `await` subscribes you to the sequence.

Check [the comment](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Interfaces/Reactive/Subjects/IConnectableObservable.cs) on `IConnectableObservable.Dispose()`

> Disposable used to disconnect the observable wrapper from its source, *causing subscribed observer to stop receiving values from the underlying observable sequence.*

This means that emiting all notifications including `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleted` is stopped.

So, if you `await` after disposing the `IConnectableObservable` you will not receive any notifications. You can `Connect` again to the `hotsource` to receive notifications.

Comment: I've updated my question to ensure I'm defiantly subscribed. It still doesn't send a complete notification. I guess its only supposed to send its source's completions.?